# Laravel Client Credentials Check in api.php

Tags: laravel, authentication, client, token, credentials

So I'm creating a laravel app where part of the front end lives on a cold fusion site and the people interacting with my API are not "users", just people signing up for seminars/consultations.  My question is I've been able to grant tokens using the grant_type client credentials and in the web.php file with ->middleware('client') attached to the route (or a route group for multiple routes) it works just fine.  However I've been told to move them into my api.php file and everything.  I cannot seem to get it to work.  In postman all I get for a response is to be brought back to the login page because I am not a logged in user.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in api file every middleware that wants to check credential use authorizing it means you should use laravel passport for

Comment: how do I make sure the token works for a "GUEST" user, like one that does not have a login?

Comment: I think the easiest way is to make a guest user and if someone sends a request to your route that not login u can log in him manually  with Auth::attempt($credentials) and get the token but if u think u want use passport u can  use predefined tokens that u can generate in your passport panel

Comment: I thought about doing that but I didn't know if a default login like that was conventional or not.